# Twill : requests.exceptions.MissingSchema

Tags: python, twill

I'm working on a simple web scraper for a page which requires users to be logged in to see its content.

```
from twill.commands import *
go("https://website.com/user")
fv("1","edit-name","NICKNAME")
fv("1","edit-pass","NICKNAME")
submit('0')
```

That is my current code. When running it, I get the following error

```
raise MissingSchema(error)
requests.exceptions.MissingSchema: Invalid URL '/user': No schema supplied. Perhaps you meant http:///user?
```

What am I doing wrong?